# X12 making fields fit

Tags: edi, x12, eai, b2b

I have a need to create an X12 810 document implementation in order to receive invoices from my customer. I have certain fields that I need like: ShipNumber, ShipmentNumbers, and ProjectCode that exist on the invoice header level. There are also fields like ExpenseType that exist on invoice detail level. In the document that I hand off to the customer it would be correct to say BIG09 should be shipnumber and can be 10 characters long? Or YNQ07 will be ProjectCode and can only be values x,y,z?

I just want to know how do I express the data I need on an X12 810 document? I'm confused because when I look at other companies X12 810 implementation I don't see how I can ask for what I need

Comment: Are you asking for a way to create an implementation guide? If you have specialized requirements, you can download a standard 810 guideline from the web and modify it to add it.  You should be using a tool like EDI Notepad to model your 810.  This will check for syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

So i think you want to create a x12 810 file from the given datas. First understand each fields in the x12 810 file.To create a file first input each segment as string(put a next line command in the end of each string) into an array and the  write each line from the array into an file and create a header to download this file as text file.Its easy